# What is the meaning of 报 in 你有报语言培训班吗?

Tags: meaning

A Chinese friend asked me:

> 你有报语言培训班吗?

I understand what she means, but I wonder what meaning 报 carries here.
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the 报 here is referring to registering/signing up/apply as in 报名.

> A: Have you registered/signed up for X class yet?
> B: Yes, I have (registered/signed up).
>
> 甲: 你 X(课/班) 报名了吗？
> 乙: 嗯 我报了。

Answer (score 3):

`报` here means to apply, sign up, register.

The sentence can be translated as `Have you applied/registered/signed up (for) the language training courses?`

Some other examples:

```
你报哪个学校了？ Which college did you apply for?
他报了400米。   He registered for the 400m (run).
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding my one cent here:

报 can be a short form for 报读 or enroll.

> Did you enroll for the language class?

Answer (score -1):

In this context 报 is used as a verb that means 'sign up for'.